# Rewriting URLs without using IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been looking for a while on how to rewrite URLs , I've seached on it in SO and Google but in vain.

My problem is that I have a small web application and I want to rewrite **all my urls**

So basically I want this :

```
localhost:56789/Controller1/Action1 => localhost:56789/something
localhost:56789/Controller1/Action2 => localhost:56789/something2
localhost:56789/Controller2/Action2 => localhost:56789/something3
```

...

Is it possible ? How ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do you mean you want `localhost:56789/something` to be routed to `localhost:56789/Controller1/Action1`? If so, that can be done easily my mapping some routes.

Comment: Yes! :) that's exactly what I want

Comment: I need some Code or a document to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up `/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`

Add this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Something",
    url: "something", //Don't prefix this with a forward slash
    defaults: new { controller = "Cotnroller1", action = "Action1" }
 );
```

You can do pretty much anything with URLs these days.

ref: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs